# How to append 2 SQL tables with different number of columns?

Tags: sql, database, apache-spark, datatables, append

I have a table (TableA) in a SQL database stored in a Server, accessible via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Then I have a Databricks notebook which creates a table (TableB) which is then appended to the one stored in the server (Table A).

To append TableB to TableA I use spark:

```
df_tableB.write.format("jdbc") \
    .mode('append') \
    .option("url", db_jdbc_url) \
    .option("driver", driver) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", db_user) \
    .option("password", db_password) \
    .save()
```

This works perfectly if the schema of TableA and TableB is the same. However I find out that now my TableB could have a slightly different schema in particular, there could be additional columns.

Therefore I wonder if there is a mode to append the tables so that all columns in common are appended as they are right now, and the new ones are appended as well displaying maybe "None". Would you be able to propose a smart and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Read the schema of `TableA` and select only those columns from `TableB`:

```
df_tableA = spark.read.format("jdbc").option(...)...load(...)
columns = [F.col(column_name) if column_name in df_tableB.schema.names else F.lit(None).alias(column_name) for column_name in df_tableA.schema.names]
df_tableB.select(columns).write.format("jdbc") \
    .mode('append') \
    .option("url", db_jdbc_url) \
    .option("driver", driver) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", db_user) \
    .option("password", db_password) \
    .save()
```

This way only columns that are present in `TableA` are selected and the order will be correct.

Comment: What if you want to add 2 cols to the rdbms table?

Comment: @ollik1 Thanks for your answer. I just tried and I get a new error: 

**AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`column.name`' given input columns:**

But I am sure that the columns are named correctly since I did not touch them and they come from the same source. Any idea why this could happen?